# Ubuntu 18.04: installing composer: Could not write to file "/usr/local/bin/composer"

Tags: 18.04, composer

I'm trying to install composer using [a tutorial](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-and-use-composer-on-ubuntu-18-04/), on Ubuntu 18.04. I'm having the following error message:

```
$ sudo php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
[sudo] password : 
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...
Could not write to file "/usr/local/bin/composer": rename(/usr/local/bin/composer-temp.phar,/usr/local/bin/composer): Is a directory
Retrying...

Could not write to file "/usr/local/bin/composer": rename(/usr/local/bin/composer-temp.phar,/usr/local/bin/composer): Is a directory
Retrying...

Could not write to file "/usr/local/bin/composer": rename(/usr/local/bin/composer-temp.phar,/usr/local/bin/composer): Is a directory
The download failed repeatedly, aborting.
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Did you read the error messages ? It complains about /usr/local/bin/composer being a directory where it expected a file (or nothing). What is the content of /usr/local/bin/composer ? If it is empty you can try to delete it,

Comment: $ ls /usr/local/bin/composer: composer.phar

Answer (score 2):

I have deleted `/usr/local/bin/composer` and started the installation process from the begining and it worked now.

When I enter the following command, I'm getting the following error message:

> $ composer

```
In JsonFile.php line 98:
                                                                               
  Could not read /home/tonguim/.composer/config.json                           
                                                                               
  file_get_contents(/home/tonguim/.composer/config.json): failed to open stre  
  am: Permission denied
```

But when using

$ sudo composer

I'm getting everything right as follow:

```
  ______
  / ____/___  ____ ___  ____  ____  ________  _____
 / /   / __ \/ __ `__ \/ __ \/ __ \/ ___/ _ \/ ___/
/ /___/ /_/ / / / / / / /_/ / /_/ (__  )  __/ /
\____/\____/_/ /_/ /_/ .___/\____/____/\___/_/
                    /_/
Composer version 2.0.12 2021-04-01 10:14:59
```

To run composer without being sudom I did the following:

```
// Clear cache
composer clearcache
// OR
composer clear-cache

// Completely remove the cache directory
sudo rm -rf ~/.composer
```